# Ruby on Rails - Render form for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, renderpartial

when I render an partial for my model I'm using:

```
<%= partial @my_model %>
```

Automatically it looks for the file ..view/my_models/_my_model.html.erb
I really like this notation because it feels the right way!

My Problem:
Now I want a notation to automatically look up for the edit partial.
Is there a way? Until now I used

```
<%= partial 'edit' %>
```

This is ok, but I have a lot of subclasses for my model and I liked the way that it automatically looks up in the right subclasses view folder for the template.
Until know I have to look for the class for my model and then call

```
<% if @my_model.class == FirstSubClass %>
    <%= partial 'firstsubclasses/_edit.html.erb' %>
<% elsif @my_model.class == SecondSubClass %>
    <%= partial 'secondsubclasses/_edit.html.erb' %>
<% end %>
```

I prefer one line :) Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= partial '#{@my_model.class.name.tableize}/_edit.html.erb' %>
```

tableize is a method of [ActiveSupport::Inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html), which includes some other cool naming manipulation methods.

Comment: Be aware that this will behave differently to the original code if the model object is any other subclass